# How to execute command on localhost depending on a remote host

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I have this:

```
- name: compile 
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: compile binary
    local_action: command make build FOO=foo1
```

I want to execute `make build FOO=bar1` *on localhost once* if host is either `bar-1` or `bar-2` (they're both in group `bars`, so distinguishing by group is fine too). I tried using `when`:

```
  - name: compile binary
    local_action: command make build FOO=foo1
    when: (inventory_hostname != "bar-1") and (inventory_hostname != "bar-2")
  - name: compile binary
    local_action: command make build FOO=bar1
    when: (inventory_hostname == "bar-1") or (inventory_hostname == "bar-2")
```

But `inventory_hostname` is always `localhost`.

In my hosts I have

```
[foos]
foo-1 ...
foo-2 ...

[bars]
bar-1 ...
bar-2 ...
```

And I run it as

```
ansible-playbook -i provision/hosts -l localhost,bars provision/deploy.yml
```

Comment: Your playbook has `hosts: localhost` – thus it will always run on localhost.

Comment: So, there is no way to know e.g. which hosts/groups were mentioned in the `-l` params from inside the playbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task will run a command on localhost **once** if the current host being operated on is part of the `bars` group.

```
   shell: echo {{ inventory_hostname }}
   run_once: true
   delegate_to: localhost
   when: "'bars' in group_names"
```

**Note**: If you plan on using `serial` mode it affects `run_once` behaviour.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me:

```
---
- hosts: localhost,test-server
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: echo {{ inventory_hostname }}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Commands are executed on localhost, but printing `localhost` and `test-server`.

Comment: This will execute twice if I have two test-servers, right? I only need it to execute once on localhost.

Comment: There is `run_once` for that. Or describe what do you want to achieve in more details in the original post.

Comment: I've added detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Way to run actions on localhost basis of hostnames in inventory

#### Command:

```
ansible-playbook -i ~/inventory_file provision/deploy.yml -e 'host_group=bars'
```

Add hosts in inventory file

#### ~/inventory_file

```
[foos]
foo-1 ...
foo-2 ...

[bars]
bar-1 ...
bar-2 ...
```

#### deploy.yml

```
 - name: compile 
   hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false

   tasks:
     - name: compile binary
       local_action: command make build FOO=foo1
       when: {{item}} not in "'bar-1','bar-2'"
       with_items:
         - groups['host_group']

     - name: compile binary
       local_action: command make build FOO=bar1
       when: {{item}} in "'bar-1','bar-2'"
       with_items:
         - groups[host_group]
```